# Can $\int_0^1\frac{1}{t}e^{-t} dt$ be analytically or numerically integrated?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, improper-integrals

The following integral has a singularity at $t = 0$ as in this situation the exponential term becomes $1$ and it no longer dominates the $\frac{1}{t}$ term.

$$f(x) = \int_0^1\frac{1}{t}e^{-t}dt$$

So is it possible to analytically or numerically integrate this function?

Comment: You might want to lookup the [*Exponential Integral*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Comment: Your definition makes no sense (the RHS does not depend on $t$). If you mean $$f(x) = \int_0^x\frac{1}{t}e^{-t} dt$$
the integral is related to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral but does **not** converge for $x=1$

Comment: This does not change anything related to convergence because you can just pull the factor $e^x$ in front of the integral.

Comment: @gammatester Ok I was trying to simplify just for the question where I am only interested in the $x = 0$. The form of it is $$f(x) = \int_0^1\frac{1}{t}e^{-t - \frac{|x|^2}{t}}dt$$.

Comment: Numerical methods work for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: @sonicboom: The integrals in your question and first comment diverge (as Ian's answer shows). The integral in your second comment converges for $x > 0$, but not for $x = 0$. If appropriate, would you please edit your question to match your intent? Thank you. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I have deleted the misleading comment.

Comment: @sonicboom This integral that you have just written is very different, because you have introduced an exponential decay near $t=0$ whenever $x \neq 0$.

Comment: @Ian Yes its fine when $x \ne 0$..that's why it's only the $x = 0$ case that I am interested in and hence why I left the $x$ out of my original post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The singularity isn't integrable, so you will have $+\infty$, as you can see by observing $\int_0^1 e^{-t}/t dt \geq \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{et} dt = +\infty$.

The question of numerically integrating $\int_0^1 t^a e^{-t}$ for $-1<a<0$ is more interesting.